# Tomcat - MySQL - Hibernate - c3p0 timeout/broken pipe

Tags: mysql, hibernate, tomcat, jdbc, c3p0

I've been struggling to make my web application(s) stop throwing broken pipe/timeout exceptions. I've read many threads ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720571/hibernate-mysql-connection-timeouts-trying-to-deal-with-thread-pooled-execu), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730827/hibernate-c3p0-mysql-broken-pipe), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104195/hibernate-tomcat-mysql-issue), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357235/hibernate-apache-tomcat-jdbcconnection-timeout-excpetion-broken-pipe) and others) and [blogs](http://www.codefin.net/2007/05/hibernate-and-mysql-connection-timeouts.html), but to no avail.

I have `c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar, hibernate-c3p0-4.1.1.Final.jar, hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar` and all required jar files in my `WEB-INF/lib` folder. I don't think the version is the problem but I figured, I should list the details. `Apache Tomcat/6.0.24`, `MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.70`. All this running on `Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS`, `lucid`.

I get the following exceptions in my catalina log after 8 hours of (db) inactivity:

```
10:18:45,657 WARN SqlExceptionHelper:143 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
10:18:45,660 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:144 - The last packet successfully received from the server was 69,956,254 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 69,956,255 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 69,956,254 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 69,956,255 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy24.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1962)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2447)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2433)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2263)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2258)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1161)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
at gr.adds.myapp.server.db.DB.getBFromUser(DB.java:49)
at gr.adds.myapp.server.BSImpl.getBusesInfo(BSImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 69,956,254 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 69,956,255 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3364)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1983)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2293)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
... 41 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3345)
... 51 more
```

Here is my `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true</property>
    <property name="connection.username">dbuser</property>
    <property name="connection.password">dbpass</property>
    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
    <!-- hibernate.cfg.xml -->

    <property name="connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
    <property name="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>
    <property name="connection.is-connection-validation-required">true</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <!-- <property name="max_fetch_depth">1</property> -->

    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<!--        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.initial_size">5</property>  -->
<!--        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property> -->
<!--        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</property> -->
<!--        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property> -->
<!--        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">250</property> -->

<!--        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">60</property> -->
<!--        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">5</property> -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads">3</property>
    <!-- no "connection.pool_size" entry! -->    
    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <!-- <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property> -->  
<!--        <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">false</property> -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">3</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">25200</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">15</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">3</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">250</property>

    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1;</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>


    <!-- Mapping files -->
            ...
</session-factory>
```

Also, I have a `c3p0.properties` file in the same folder as `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true
c3p0.preferredTestQuery=SELECT 1;
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.ManagementCoordinator=com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.NullManagementCoordinator
```

My tomcat `tomcat6/conf/server.xml` file has:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="AJP/1.3" connectionTimeout="20000" URIEncoding="UTF-8" redirectPort="8443" />
```

My `/etc/mysql/my.conf` file is default.

I should tell you I tried many many combinations.
To start, adding the `wait_timeout` in `/etc/mysql/my.conf` doesn't seem to have any effect (UPDATED->READ UPDATE BELOW). I changed it to 60 (for 60 seconds), waited a few minutes and did not get the exception I was expecting. I haven't waited 8 hours since putting that value there but I believe the results would be the same. Without the `wait_timeout` property, after 8 hours I get similar exceptions as above every time (with only time difference).

I've read that the `hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period` should be less than the mysql `wait_timeout`, which it is why I have 7 hours (25200 seconds) for the first while the latter by default is 8 hours. I've played around with the other values as well but they don't seem to matter. You see several commented out values in my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file above because I've tried many many combinations. I've read that the `testConnectionOnCheckout` is expensive but I added it to see if I can make this work.

Of course, restarting tomcat (`sudo service tomcat6 restart`) works, but this is not the solution.

Does anyone have an idea what I can try/change to make this stop giving me this exception? Any "magic" values that will make it work?

**UPDATE:**

Ok, I wasn't putting the wait_timout inside [mysqld].
So I put in my.conf

```
wait_timeout=120
```

and in hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">80</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">60</property>
```

Now the error I get is:

```
14:15:41,746 WARN NewPooledConnection:486 - [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
14:15:41,747 WARN NewPooledConnection:487 - [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed. ] which will not be reported to listeners!
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1205)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1197)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4186)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4152)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:525)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 300,078 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 18 milliseconds ago.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3102)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2991)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3532)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2293)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy24.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1962)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2447)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2433)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2263)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2258)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1161)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
at gr.adds.myapp.server.db.DB.getBFromUser(DB.java:49)
at gr.adds.myapp.server.BSImpl.getBusesInfo(BSImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2552)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3002)
... 53 more
14:15:41,751 WARN SqlExceptionHelper:143 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08003
14:15:41,752 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:144 - No operations allowed after connection closed.
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:68)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:146)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy23.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:147)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:166)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:145)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1720)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:828)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2447)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2433)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2263)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2258)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1161)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
at gr.adds.myapp.server.db.DB.getBFromUser(DB.java:49)
at gr.adds.myapp.server.BSImpl.getBusesInfo(BSImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1205)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1197)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4186)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4152)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:525)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Any ideas? Shouldn't the `wait_timeout > c3p0.idle_test_period > c3p0.timeout`?

**UPDATE 7th Oct:**

Still same timeout, but I added logging info in my `log4j.properties` file to make sure c3p0 is running with the desired values in my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file and sure enough I got:

```
11:13:09,393 INFO MLog:92 - MLog clients using log4j logging.
11:13:09,477 INFO C3P0Registry:216 - Initializing c3p0-0.9.2.1 [built 20-March-2013 11:16:28 +0000; debug? true; trace: 10]
11:13:09,627 INFO AbstractPoolBackedDataSource:522 - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@3d0991ef [ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@b336cd6b [ acquireIncrement -> 1, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> z8kflt8x14i4fy2kk9fga|7eac4d3b, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 60, initialPoolSize -> 3, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 120, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 25, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 1, nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@ebdc296f [ description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> z8kflt8x14i4fy2kk9fga|1fbbc779, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true, properties -> {autoReconnect=true, is-connection-validation-required=true, useUnicode=true, user=******, password=******, characterEncoding=UTF-8, autoReconnectForPools=true} ], preferredTestQuery -> select 1;, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> z8kflt8x14i4fy2kk9fga|27b104d7, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]
```

Also updated to the latest libraries just in case, but still the same: `c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar, hibernate-c3p0-4.2.6.Final.jar, hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar, hibernate-core-4.2.6.Final.jar, mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is almost always caused by a firewall or some other networking component shutting-down an idle connection. The solution is to use a connection-test statement, which is looks like you're doing. I don't know anything about `C3P0` (other than that it hasn't release 1.0 yet) so I can't tell if your configuration is correct for preventing idle-timeouts.

I'm wondering why you aren't using Tomcat's built-in connection pool. It seems to work perfectly fine and configurations Just Work.